# Python Pandas aggregation with condition

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, conditional-statements, aggregation

I need to group my dataframe and use several aggregation functions on different columns. And some of this aggregation have conditions.

Here is an example. The data are all the orders from 2 customers and I would like to calculate some information on each customer. Like their orders count, their total spendings and average spendings.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'order_id' : range(1,9),
        'cust_id' : [1]*5 + [2]*3,
        'order_amount' : [100,50,70,75,80,105,30,20],
        'cust_days_since_reg' : [0,10,25,37,52,0,17,40]}

orders = pd.DataFrame(data)

aggregation = {'order_id' : 'count',
               'order_amount' : ['sum', 'mean']}

cust = orders.groupby('cust_id').agg(aggregation).reset_index()
cust.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in cust.columns.values]
```

This works fine and gives me :

[image]
_

But I have to add an aggregation function with a argument and a condition : the amount a customer spent in his first X months (X must be customizable)

Since I need an argument in this aggregation I tried :

```
def spendings_X_month(group, n_months):
    return group.loc[group['cust_days_since_reg'] <= n_months*30, 
                     'order_amount'].sum()

aggregation = {'order_id' : 'count',
               'order_amount' : ['sum',
                                 'mean',
                                 lambda x: spendings_X_month(x, 1)]}

cust = orders.groupby('cust_id').agg(aggregation).reset_index()
```

But that last line gets me the error : `KeyError: 'cust_days_since_reg'`.
It must be a scoping error, the `cust_days_since_reg` column must not be visible in this situation.

I could calculate this last column separately and then join the resulting dataframe to the first but there must be a better solution, that makes every thing in only one groupby.

Could anyone help me with this problem please ?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `agg`, because each function working only with one column, so this kind of filtering based of another col is not possible.

Solution use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
def spendings_X_month(group, n_months):
    a = group['order_id'].count()
    b = group['order_amount'].sum()
    c = group['order_amount'].mean()
    d = group.loc[group['cust_days_since_reg'] <= n_months*30, 
                     'order_amount'].sum()
    cols = ['order_id_count','order_amount_sum','order_amount_mean','order_amount_spendings']
    return pd.Series([a,b,c,d], index=cols)

cust = orders.groupby('cust_id').apply(spendings_X_month, 1).reset_index()
print (cust)
   cust_id  order_id_count  order_amount_sum  order_amount_mean  \
0        1             5.0             375.0          75.000000   
1        2             3.0             155.0          51.666667   

   order_amount_spendings  
0                   220.0  
1                   135.0
```